# $\sim$ on $R \times (R \backslash \{0\})$ show it is an equivalence relation and a congruence [R is an integral domain]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$\sim$on $R \times (R \backslash \{0\})$ by $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ means $ad=bc$

Note:$R$ is an integral domain

The operations are $(a,b)+(c,d) = (ad+bc,bd)$ and $(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac, db)$

Reflexive: $ab = ba \implies (a,b) \sim (a,b)$

Symmetric: Let $(a,b) \sim (c,d) $ this gives $ad = bc$  and we are in an integral domain thus $cb = da \implies (c,d) \sim (a,b)$

Transitive: Let $(a,b) \sim (c,d), (c,d) \sim (e,f)$

$ad=bc$ and $cf=de$

thus $adf=daf=bcf=cbf=cfb=fcb=deb=edb \implies daf = dbe$ and we have cancellativity b/c R is an integral domain and $d \neq 0$ thus $af =be$ therefore $(a,b) \sim (e,f)$

Congruence: This is where I am stuck on showing the compatibility with addition and multiplication.

**EDIT:**

$(r,s) \in R \times R \backslash \{0\}$ and $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$

Additive compatiblity:

$((rb+sa)sd) = ((rd + sc)sb) \implies (rb+sa,sb) \sim (rd + sc,sd) \\ \implies (r,s) + (a,b) \sim (r,s) + (c,d)   $

Multiplicative compatibility:

$ rasd = sbrc 
  \implies (ra, sb) \sim (rc, sd)
 \implies (r,s)\cdot(a,b) \sim (r,s)\cdot(c,d)$

And b/c R is a integral domain it is commutative, and addition is commutative thus from the other side would be valid too.

Like this??

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Wonderful, thank you!